# Rotation Matrix about arbitrary direction

Tags: matrix-equations, rotations

I know the rotation matrix about main axis are

[image]

But I'm asking for rotation about an arbitrary direction for example about a given arbitrary direction modified by $n$. 
thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this out for size inside.mines.edu/fs_home/gmurray/ArbitraryAxisRotation/

Comment: @Rumplestillskin please correct your link.

Comment: you can always align the frame in that $n$ direction and you can rotate in that plane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing you almost surely want is [Rodrigues' Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Rodrigues_formula), which for a given length-one vector $v = (a, b, c)$ and angle $\theta$ gives the matrix for rotation of angle $\theta$ around $v$. (It also expresses this rotation in terms of cross products, which may prove more useful than the matrix form.)

Answer (score 0):

If $r$ is a line of  $\mathbb{R}^3$ passing through the origin, $e_1$ an  unitary vector in the direction of $r$ and $B=\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $e_1\times e_2=e_3$, it can be proved that the rotation matrix with angle $\alpha$ and axis $r$  is $$G=E\begin{bmatrix}{1}&{0}&{0}\\{0}&{\cos \alpha}&{-\text{sen }\alpha}\\{0}&{\text{sen }}\alpha&{\;\;\cos \alpha}\end{bmatrix}E^T,\quad E=\begin{bmatrix}{e_1},e_2,e_3\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Really thanks for your complete answer

Comment: Not sure if I am seeing this correctly, but isn't E a 1x3, that makes G a 1x1 (1x3 times 3x3 times 3x1)?